# How much Server Optimization Matters for SEO?

Tags: seo, seo-audit

I want to know what is the value of server optimization except https implementation, shared or dedicated server. If there are any others things I should include in my server optimization template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to have super fast dedicated server with SSD, HTTP/2, latest PHP/MySQL and unique IP localized in the country you plan to rank for. Domain should have SSL certificate.

When it comes to optimization strictly related to server settings then you should:

- [Enable gzip compression](https://gtmetrix.com/enable-gzip-compression.html)
- [Add Expires headers](https://gtmetrix.com/add-expires-headers.html)
- [Leverage browser caching](https://gtmetrix.com/leverage-browser-caching.html)

All of the above you can easily implement in your .htaccess file (if you are using Apache server).

Comment: Hi,

I am not convinced with the answers. All the above mentioned things I do but I am looking for something potential to add.

Comment: If you already implemented all from above then you can also check your website with [Google Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) to see many more things you can improve. You can also pay attention to server security: set server signature off, disable directory browsing and set custom error pages.

Answer (score 1):

The SEO-relevant difference between shared and dedicated server could be

- IP neighborhood - bad sites, which are hosted on the same server (even on shared server you can buy own IP)
- Speed - if any website is badly coded or hacked, the whole server could get slow or go down,
- Security - again, if somebody on the same server was hacked, and the hacker got it to escalate his access rights, he could get an access to your host too

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I check performance (speed), multiple IPs (or at least my own IP) and uptime.

First thing is to guarantee a good page load. For that I check:

- Server load time (first pixel)
- Possibility to install software to improve website performance (memchached, pagespeed, gzip, etc). Normally is only allow in VPS but not in shared hosting.

Next step is to check IP options:

- If we have multiple sites, the possibility to have a different IP for each one
- If it's a shared server, check bad neighbors in order to prevent future problems
- If the site is country-oriented, I always choose an IP located in that country

Other options:

- SSL certificated
- Uptime (at least 99%)